# ¿Puedo usar una base de datos de SQL Server en mi proyecto de RAILS 4 en ubuntu?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Quiero desarrollar un sitio web en RAILS 4 pero necesariamente debo de usar una base de datos existente de SQL Server, ¿sera posible usarla en ubuntu o necesariamente debo de programar en Windows?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server no lo puedes instalar en ubuntu, de todas formas si tienes una base existente de SQL Server ya funcionando en algun servidor, puedes hacer tu desarrollo en RAILS y conectarte a esta base SQL Server, o puede armarte un entorno separado con Windows de S.O. y SQL Server instalado para tu ambiente de desarrollo. Y tu sitio web en RAILS lo seguirias desarrollando en tu maquina con Ubuntu.

Comment: Hola @Fer gracias por tu respuesta, se ven muy interesante esas dos opciones, la segunda opcion no la entendi muy bien, seria que programaria en el entorno de desarrollo en windows y sql server y luego en los otros ambientes migre a ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente tus opciones son:

- Existe una versión de sql server para linux, pero aún está en desarrollo. Si quieres acceder a un preview de esta versión tienes que inscribirte en https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/sql-server-on-linux.aspx pero no te aseguro que sea estable del todo, tampoco que sea compatible con los drivers sql server para Ruby.
- Correr sql server en un equipo dedicado (OJO, aquí me refiero a una instancia de DESARROLLO, no una instancia con datos reales) y que tu aplicación rails se conecte a él. Para mi ésta es la mejor opción, sin embargo necesitas un equipo extra que corra la aplicación.
- virtualizar una máquina windows en tu ubuntu con virtualbox y ahí instalar SQL server. esta opción es la más barata, sin embargo alentará tu equipo de desarrollo considerablemente ya que tendrás 2 sistemas operativos corriendo.
- desarrollar la aplicación rails en windows. Esta es la opción más simple, sin embargo te espera un mar de incompatibilidades a medida que integres nuevas gemas a tu proyecto que no sean compatibles con windows.

Comment: Hola @Alter gracias por tu respuesta, en cuanto a tu segundo punto te refieres al uso de un ordenador como servidor y tener la base de datos alojada en el y conectamer desde ubuntu a este?

Comment: @Ing.LuisC si, puede ser un ordenador común y corriente que haga las veces de servidor o buscar algún hosting que te ofrezca sql server gratuitamente (o pagado si tienes los recursos), aunque a decir verdad, desconozco que servicios se ofrecen para sql server, ya que nunca he trabajado con ese motor de bd. Igual un ordenador local va a ser mas rápido, ya que estará en tu red local.

Comment: Entiendo @Alter, esa podria ser la mejor opcion. Pregunta: ¿si utilizo un servidor que pueda usar para hosting de la base de datos, cuando termine mi aplicación rails, podre montarla en el mismo servidor de la base de datos sql server?

Comment: Las opciones 1, 3 y 4 que te mencioné funcionan todas en una única máquina, así que sí, de poder, se puede. Ahora que una de esas opciones sea la mejor para correr la app en un __entorno real de producción__, lo desconozco ya que nunca he desarrollado una app con esas características. Creo que por rendimiento y uso de recursos la mejor opción sería la 4, correr todo en windows, pero te insisto que eventualmente podrías tener problemas de compatibilidad con gemas, al menos las más populares suelen ser compatibles con windows, así que final todo depende de la complejidad que vaya a tener tu app.

Comment: Entiendo @Alter y en el caso de montar una maquina virtual dentro de ubuntu como haría para poder hacer la conexión de la base de datos desde mi ubuntu a la maquina virtual?